# Convert SQL to Linq Lambda

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I have two entities (EF 6) named Purchases and Packets. I am able to Join these two but not quite sure how do I count the Packets contained in the given Purchase. I have this SQL query to be converted to LINQ (Lambda expression preferred).

Thank you

```
SELECT 
    Pur.*, 
    Pac.Price, 
    (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM Packets WHERE PurchaseID = Pur.ID) AS PacketCount
FROM 
    Purchases AS Pur
INNER JOIN 
    Packets AS Pac 
ON 
    Pur.ID = Pac.PurchaseID
```

NOTE: I checked the answered Q's but none of them is addressing my issue.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the relationship between the two class objects. Is it a two way navigational property?

Comment: Wrong question. If the entity `Purchage` is related to the entity `Package` through a `Packages` relation, the only thing you need is to write `myPurcahe.Packages.Count()`. If you find yourself writing joins between entities, your domain model is probably wrong

Comment: That's what I was thinking @Panagiotis, I feel a look at the objects would help.

Comment: There is no a "two way relashionship" ... however, the table Packages contains PurchasesID flag. Based on this ID i need to count the packages contained in the given Purchase. Anyone willing to help translating the above query to linq? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in LINQ (far from it) but I have done something similar.  You say you have done the join already.  If it is along the lines of:

```
var joinList = (from Item1 in Purchases
                            join Item2 in Packets
                            on Item1.Id equals Item2.PurchaseId 
                            select new { Item1, Item2 }).ToList();
```

Then you can go:

```
var subList = joinList.Where(j => j.Item1.Id == myId).Select(s => { new s.Item1, s.Item2.Price, Count = joinList.Where(j => j.Item1.Id == myId).Count() }).ToList();
```

This will give you a List similar to the recordset returned by your SQL.  Note that you will need to break out all the fields in Item1 (equivalent to Purchases.*).  The alternative is to name them all in the Select (as s.Item2.Price).

HTH